# Interpretation of WRITTEN LARGE

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across the following statement:

> International law, after all, is a system of manners **written large**.

I'm a native English speaker and translator, and I'm having a hard time translating this statement because I'm not clear on what is meant by *written large*. I wouldn't even know how to paraphrase this.

Please answer if you're sure of the answer - no guesses please.

Comment: From the definition of [*write*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/write) is the more common expression ***writ*** *large*: "on a larger scale or in a more prominent manner // the problems of modern totalitarianism are only our own problems *writ large*."

Comment: Thank you, Jason, writ large definitely makes more sense.

Comment: ["The self is simply society **writ small**."](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/153176/2637) See also [“Writ large”, “Writ small”, and others](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52521/writ-large-writ-small-and-others)